# Hololens Wifi card seem to buffer received udp messages

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, udp, hololens

Currently Im building a simple collaboration room for Hololens 2, I want people to be able to see each other.
So I built a system using udp socket to share the hand of user across network (client-server).

To try proving that my system is not at fault I tried a simple experiment ,
I have 1 server and 2 clients, 1 of the client is on Holo 2 and the other on windows standalone both are connected to the server via wifi.
When both are connected they can see each other avatar as well as their own (The computer simulate hand with the MicrosoftRealityToolkit)

Inside the hololens when the user move his hand, we can see the Pc client receiving it instantly with a really small delay
however the Holo recv his own move way later (0.5s delay approximatively)

Same experiment with the pc moving his avatar, It will recv his own move instantly , however the holo will once again recv it with a delay.

Also I noticed that if I increase the messages frequency from the server the hololens will start to lose all the packets

It's really strange because all the packets are received, all the movements are well restored they just have a big delay on holo. I suppose that the networks card is at fault and buffer the received msgs, but Im not knowledgeable enough on network stuff to really understand what's happening there.

Comment: is the PC client also connected via WiFi or Lan?

Comment: The Pc client is also connected via WiFi , the Pc and the Holo clients are on the exact same conditions

Comment: Have you tried to analyze HoloLens' network latency with other professional tools? According to your description, I think it is possible due to your app has an underperforming frame rate when sharing object movements. Since the hardware performance limitations of HoloLens, it is unlikely to run as fast as a computer. Not sure if this is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/performance-recommendations-for-unity

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here are the couple of things you can do.

1. Try with TCP communication so you can keep track of the packages.
2. Don't send the the pose values constantly, just send when the pose changes and when you receive the data on the Hololens, perform interpolation to get a smoother results. This will make it feel like you have less lag.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply to this, but hopefully helps someone:
Hololens seems to absolutely hate receiving UDP broadcasts. Was having identical latency issue, even with all other devices disconnected from the network, simple packets, and sending at a far lower framerate than the hololens. Try addressing the hololens IP only, not the broadcast address, even if it means you need a second server running for all the other devices